# Linq Subquery in IQueryable Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, subquery

I am having problems with subqueries in a linq-to-entities IQueryable query.

Can anybody tell me what is the correct way to do a sub query when building up an IQueryable query? Based on my full example below.

I get the following error when ToArray() is called on the query:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet`1[MyDomain.NewsWorthyPressReleases.NewsWorthyWire] Set[NewsWorthyWire]()' method, 
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

So for example you can see one of my subqueries here:

```
BwIncluded = (from abw in Context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>()
                                          where abw.WireId == PressWireIds.BUID
                                          where abw.NewsWorthyCampaignId == nc.Id
                                          select abw).Any(),
```

I am trying to populate BwIncluded with true or false if any() exists.

And the entire build up of the query is as follows, it is IMPORTANT to understand where the sub-queries are used:

```
private Func<EntityFramework.IDbContext, IQueryable<NewsWorthyPressRelease>> GetSearchNewsWorthyQuery(NewsWorthySearchFields searchFields)
    {
        return context =>
        {
            //domain models
            var newsWorthyCampaigns = context.Set<NewsWorthyCampaign>();
            var wires = context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>();
            var campaigns = context.Set<Campaign>();


            //predicates
            var newsWorthyCampaignPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<NewsWorthyCampaign>();
            var wirePredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<NewsWorthyWire>();
            var campaignPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Campaign>();


            // build up the predicate queries

            //Status was input
            if (searchFields.StatusId.HasValue && searchFields.StatusId.Value > 0)
            {
                newsWorthyCampaignPredicate = newsWorthyCampaignPredicate.And(x => x.Id == searchFields.StatusId);
            }

            //Id was input
            if (searchFields.Id.HasValue && searchFields.Id.Value > 0)
            {
                wirePredicate = wirePredicate.And(x => x.Id == searchFields.Id); 
            }

            //Title was input
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchFields.Title))
            {
                wirePredicate = wirePredicate.And(x => x.Title.Contains(searchFields.Title));
            }

            //Wire was input
            if (searchFields.PressWireId.HasValue && searchFields.PressWireId.Value > 0)
            {
                wirePredicate = wirePredicate.And(x => x.Id == searchFields.PressWireId);
            }

            //Created By was chosen
            if (searchFields.CreatedById.HasValue && searchFields.CreatedById.Value > 0)
            {
                campaignPredicate = campaignPredicate.And(x => x.IdentityId == searchFields.CreatedById);
            }

            //Create Date From was chosen
            if (searchFields.DateCreatedFrom.HasValue)
            {
                campaignPredicate = campaignPredicate.And(y => y.CreationDate >= searchFields.DateCreatedFrom);
            }

            //Create Date To was chosen
            if (searchFields.DateCreatedTo.HasValue)
            {
                campaignPredicate = campaignPredicate.And(y => y.CreationDate <= searchFields.DateCreatedTo);
            }

            //the query
            var nwprQuery = (from nc in  newsWorthyCampaigns.Where(newsWorthyCampaignPredicate)
                             join w in wires.Where(wirePredicate)
                                on nc.Id equals w.NewsWorthyCampaignId
                            join c in campaigns.Where(campaignPredicate) 
                                on nc.CampaignId equals c.Id
                            select new NewsWorthyPressRelease
                            {
                                Id = nc.Id,
                                Title = w.Title,
                                //BwIncluded = false,
                                //GnIncluded = false,
                                //PrIncluded = false,
                                BwIncluded = (from abw in Context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>()
                                              where abw.WireId == PressWireIds.BUID
                                              where abw.NewsWorthyCampaignId == nc.Id
                                              select abw).Any(),
                                GnIncluded = (from agw in Context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>()
                                              where agw.WireId == PressWireIds.GLID
                                              where agw.NewsWorthyCampaignId == nc.Id
                                              select agw).Any(),
                                PrIncluded = (from anw in Context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>()
                                              where anw.WireId == PressWireIds.PRID
                                              where anw.NewsWorthyCampaignId == nc.Id
                                              select anw).Any(),
                                CreatedBy = c.CreatedBy.FirstName + " " + c.CreatedBy.Surname,
                                CreateDate = c.CreationDate,
                                Status = nc.NewsWorthyStatus.Name,
                            }).AsNoTracking();

            return nwprQuery;
        };
    }
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be lowercase `context`?

Comment: @JeffMercado I have tried with both upper and lower, same error unfortunately. Any other thoughts? Are sub-queries like this possible?

Comment: If you asked me, the subquery looks fine.  You're not using anything that would look like is not supported. I asked about the case of `Context` because that's the name of the parameter.  I wasn't sure if that was intentional. I guess one thing you might want to try is to use `wires` in those queries instead (since you have it already set on top).

Comment: It looks like entity framework does not see `NewsWorthyWire` as part of the model but as a regular c# class. Check that it's part of the model.

Comment: @tzachs `NewsWorthyWire` is part of the model i think. You can see it declared also as var `wires` at the line `var wires = context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>();` and used in the join statement. If i comment out the sub queries, there is no error thrown, even when `wires`is still used in the join. So I *think* EF see's it as part of the model. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @JeffMercado Its strange, if i take out one of the sub queries and set it as its own `var`, that var will get populated with out any error: `var BwIncluded = (from abw in context.Set<NewsWorthyWire>()
                                  where abw.WireId == PressWireIds.BUSINESS_WIRE_ID
                                  where abw.NewsWorthyCampaignId == 1
                                  select abw).Any();` - but when it is a subquery it errors! Any other thoughts? thanks.

Comment: So why don't you use the `wires` variable instead in your subqueries?